# Is cost directly proportional to average no.of queries in snow flakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This post is all about warehouse profilinging  with help of link below.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/understanding-snowflake-utilization-warehouse-profiling/

select * from table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history(date_range_start=>dateadd('hour',-1,current_timestamp())));

warehouse load

Below is the part of the  output for duration of 1 hr(13:00hrs) with 5 mins interval.

Pic 1

[image]
Conclusions from above output

1)
AVG_QUEUED_LOAD ,
AVG_QUEUED_PROVISIONING,
AVG_BLOCKED
is zero, so I don't need to worry about either scaling up/scaling out .

2)As i see the value for  AVG_RUNNING   between 13:20 and 13:30,I can conclude that i have few queries running using warehouse (XXXXXXXXX).

3)Warehouse is idle  for most of the time except 10 mins in the duration of 1 hr.

FYI- The auto suspend value for the warehouse is configured as 1 min.

I used the below query to know the average credits used for the warehouse XXXXXXXXX

with cte as (
  select date_trunc('hour', start_time) as start_time, end_time, warehouse_name, credits_used
  from table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history(dateadd('days',-1,current_date()),current_date()))
  where warehouse_name = 'XSMALL')
select date_trunc('hour', a.start_time) as start_time, avg(AVG_RUNNING), avg(credits_used), avg(AVG_RUNNING) / avg(credits_used) * 100 
from table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history(dateadd('days',-1,current_date()),current_date())) a
join cte b on a.start_time = date_trunc('hour', a.start_time)
where a.warehouse_name = 'XSMALL'
group by 1
order by 1;

output:

Pic2

[image]

conclusion from the output

1)13 hour in 18 may AVG(AVG_RUNNING) recorded as 0.02, which can be attributed to the AVG_RUNNING    value at the same hour in pic 1

2) AVG(CREDITS_USED) at 13 hour is 0.7969887816 ,-its understandable that we see credits used because we have queries running during 13 hour.

warehouse load

Below is the part of the  output for duration of 1 hr(12:00hrs) with 5 mins interval.

Pic3

[image]

Questions

1)Why do we see AVG(AVG_RUNNING) as Zero in pic 2 though we have some queries running at 12:00 hrs in pic3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into your source data? Because

```
select *  from table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history(dateadd('days',-5,current_date()),current_date())) where warehouse_name = 'XSMALL';
```

Does not have a record per every hour. And you're doing a

```
a.start_time = date_trunc('hour', a.start_time)
```

so basically: you have 24 hours, and 1 record there from let's say 1am to 2am. So your averages return that and that only, and then you assign that 1am to 2am usage to every single hour in the day - of course it's going to be similar, just I'm not exactly sure what the idea behind this is (I can see you took the query from the blog - but I can also see his charts are showing he's been running something constantly on that WH)

Comment: Got it                                                                                                                              
       Average credits used =sum of the credits for the whole day/number of hours in a day. 
                                                           Modified the original post. stil i am looking for clarity on question 1, regarding 12 hr where i see  average of average running  as zero pic 2 though i have average running  as 0.2,0.39,0.05 in pic3.

Comment: generally queries don't always use warehouses - sometimes they can retrieve result from cache and warehouse is not needed (or sometimes they are queries that only use metadata results - like calculating counts etc, they also don't use warehouse in Snowflake)